# German umlaute represented by questionmarks when latin1 is used

Tags: mysql, mariadb, character-set

I'm almost certain this has come up before but I couldn't find anything regarding it.

My problem is that I've a database and a database server (and every table and column inside) set to latin1/latin1_general_ci.

Curiously when I connect with a client (for example HeidiSQL) client specific variables regarding character sets are set to `utf8mb4`, even more curious: äüöß are shown correctly.

When I execute `SET NAMES latin1;` and check again, the variables are set to `latin1`, as they should be, but the Umlaute are now displayed as question marks. This is also true if they where inserted *AFTER* `SET NAMES latin1;` was executed.

Another database server is completely set to utf8, except the database my program works with, which is again set to latin1. If I execute `SET NAMES latin1;` there it works as expected.

Could someone explain/tell me what is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

The `variables` I'm talking about are:

- character_set_client *[Global/Default: latin1]*
- character_set_connection *[Global/Default: latin1]*
- character_set_database *[Global/Default: latin1]*
- character_set_results *[Global/Default: latin1]*
- character_set_server *[Global/Default: latin1]*
- collation_connection *[Global/Default: latin1_general_ci]*

After some toying around it seems like `character_set_results` is the problematic one here. Setting it to latin1, while leaving the other ones at utf8mb4, results in question marks being displayed. Still no idea why this happens.

**edit**

Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE adressen`:

```
CREATE TABLE `adressen` (
  `ID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Strasse` longtext,
  `Strasse2` longtext,
  `Hausnummer` longtext,
  `Postleitzahl` longtext,
  `Ort` longtext NOT NULL,
  `Postfach` longtext,
  `IDLand` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Laengengrad` float NOT NULL,
  `Breitengrad` float NOT NULL,
  `Adresszusatz` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_Adressen_Land` (`IDLand`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Adressen_Land` FOREIGN KEY (`IDLand`) REFERENCES `laender` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=137205 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`SELECT STRASSE, HEX(STRASSE) FROM adressen WHERE STRASSE LIKE 'ä%'`:
    Ä[...];C4[...]

According to [Wikipedia's article about ISO8859](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859) that's latin1 alright.

**edit2**

After some further reading I found that both, HeidiSQL *and* .NET handle text in utf8 / unicode [at least by default]. The solution to this question is thus to convert everything to utf8mb4_unicode_ci as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/937093) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Question Marks" in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .  In particular,

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

Since you seem to be aiming for `latin1`, not `utf8`, see "Test the data" in that link.  `äüöß` will be hex `E4 FC F6 DF` in latin1, or `C3A4 C3BC C3B6 C39F` in utf8/utf8mb4.

`SET NAMES` establishes the encoding in the *client*, not the server.  The table's encoding is based on `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; let's see that.

**OR...**

It is OK if you want `latin1` used in the columns/tables, but your client wants `utf8`.  Then the connection setting (to say `utf8` / `UTF-8`) or the use of `SET NAMES utf8` (after connecting) will alert MySQL to convert as data is transferred between the client and the server and database.

(With latin1, you are limited to Western European characters.)

Comment: thank's for the explanation. I added the required information to my answer. As I want to stay with latin1, I'm going to assume that I'd have to 'interchange' latin1 and utf8mb4 in your linked answer/your quoted text.

Comment: After some further research I'm going to mark your answer as 'the' answer as by doing what you wrote down I was able to verify that the storage/database side did everything as 'told' but the viewers (HeidiSQL/.NET strings) are defaulting to utf8 or unicode and thus can not handle latin1 encoded strings by default.

Comment: I updated my Answer to take into consideration your Comment.

Comment: My paltry notes notes on .NET say "Connector/.NET possibly defaults to latin1. Consider changing 'connection string' if you need utf8. ", "ADO.NET "charset=utf8"", and "<%Response.charset="utf-8"%>"